# How do I decide when to use Ansible gce_pd vs. gcp_compute_disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

I want to create a standard persistent disk, format and mount it on multiple VM instances.

There are two Ansible tasks that create persistent disks: `gce_pd` and `gcp_compute_disk`. Which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you should use `gcp_compute_disk`, based simply on the fact that [it actually exists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_disk_module.html). A quick search does not show that the other is part of Ansible, nor was I able to find a third party module with that name; perhaps it is a local module provided internally at your company?

It seems you were actually talking about a module with a different name, `gce_pd`. That module appears to have been someone's personal project, albeit someone at Google. `gcp_compute_disk` is Google's official contribution to Ansible, so I still recommend you use that one.

Comment: I found [`gcp_pd` in the Ansible documents](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gce_pd_module.html). However, it does not appear much outside this page.

Comment: @JohnMcGehee Well, since it was misspelled, I had no chance to find it!

Comment: Ah, indeed sir! Spelling corrected. The gce_ prefix certainly is a bad smell.